# GNSS : How to analyze and correct the impact of Doppler rate on Acquisition CAF?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, gps, gnss, dsss, spread

Taking GPS L1C/A cold(initial) acquisition as an example. If there is a doppler rate(Hz/sec) on the received signal and GNSS receiver has performed a mixture of coherent and non-coherent integration to compute a CAF(Cross Ambiguity Function), then I have 2 questions :

1. How would this doppler rate change the peak position in both code-delay axis and doppler axis.
2. And, how can we correct this error at the end of every integration period without implementing a tracking loop. Even approximate correction will do.

We can assume that the coherent integration duration is 20msec(data bit duration) and we are doing non-coherent integration of 50 such coherent sums to get 1sec of total integration time.
I am referring to coherent integration as:
$$S_i(\tau, f_d) = \frac{1}{N}\sum^{N-1}_{n=0}r[n]e^{-j2\pi f_d n}c[n-\tau]$$
$r[n]$ is the received signal with the delay $\tau$, doppler $f_d$ and doppler rate $f_r$ unknown. $n=0, 1, 2, 3, ..., N-1$ corresponds to samples of duration 20msec.

Non-Coherent Integration will be :
$$S(\tau, f_d) = \sum^{49}_{i=0}|S_i(\tau, f_d)|^2$$